# Logic App - GET Azure Tenant, Client ID, Secret using Functions/Expressions?

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

Is there an option to GET Tenant, Client ID, and Secret using Function/Expression or any other method instead of manually typing in these fields?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no connectors / expression within logic app that can help you with this.

However, you could store the values in a blob storage / table storage (any storage that can be accessed securely using the logic app connector - anonymous access would not be advisable)  and use the obtained values in your subsequent steps.

Comment: Please consider accepting this solution if it had helped :)
https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, we can't do it. We can just get these values from your registered app page manually.

If allow us to get them by expressions or apis, it will cause security problem.